# interactive dialog creation with opengl

Tags: c++, c, opengl

How can I create authentication screen over using OpenGl ? Are there any tutorial or web page ?

NOTE : I have not found any, if I found, I would not ask the question.If there are any page, just give a name so that I can erase this question.

Please look the image on the http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13169_01/ales/docs22/integrateappenviron/wwimages/aldsp4%20client%20login.gif

EDIT : I want to take input from screen .

Comment: So you want to create a UI inside an OpenGL window? There are various toolkits which can do that. This post on the Gamedev SE lists various options: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/good-gui-for-opengl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL is not the library you are looking for, there are many thing you can do with it but this is not one of that, for the graphic user interface you can use GLUI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_User_Interface_Library

for some more articulated you can use AntTweakBar
[http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools:anttweakbar](http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools%3aanttweakbar)

Both are well integrated with OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

You can force this by just drawing all the buttons and implement a kind of text field, but this is not what OpenGL is made for.
At your place I would use a language like Objective-C for Mac platforms, and C# for Windows platforms.If instead you want to stick with C++, then use a library like Qt.

Comment: To clarify a bit, on the Mac everything is OpenGL underneath. The Cocoa framework (accessible through Objective-C) handles the details of drawing the bits and managing the user input that's needed for a GUI. Writing all this stuff in OpenGL yourself would be a **huge** task.