# with opengl UI security issue

Tags: c, opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [interactive dialog creation with opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551346/interactive-dialog-creation-with-opengl)

Since Authentication dialog takes password from user, at any time it prints out password in that form "* * * * * * * * * ". Via opengl UI, how can I do that  ?

see image http://media.sharewareconnection.com/images/large/authentication-132.gif

Comment: How are you drawing text in the first place to the framebuffer? Using a Bitmapfont or truetype? You could simply draw an '*' character for every entered character in the password field then.

Comment: @Bart I don't know what the site policy says, but I don't think it is a good idea to link a closed post as exact duplicate.

Comment: @Lundin That duplicate is an earlier question by the OP, which essentially boils down to the exact same question and has similar problems as this one.

Comment: @Bart Aha, fair enough then.

Comment: FYI: Asking the same question *again* is not how you attract answers. If your question was ignored, overlooked, or otherwise unanswered, you have to earn some rep by contributing to the community and post a bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Via opengl UI, how can I do that ?

OpenGL is not a UI system. It's a drawing API, and does not even deal with user input. It can of course be used as a backend to draw GUI widgets, like text or password entry fields, but that's not part of the functionality of OpenGL itself.

So either you're implementing your toolkit yourself: Then you're the one responsible to draw the desired replacement character (or just leave it blank).

Or you're using some GUI toolkit: Then you should read up the documentation of that toolkit, how to do it, because OpenGL is just the "pen and paper" it uses to draw stuff to a framebuffer.